How to crop assets image with out any package use in flutter
i have one assets image and on this image one container i have to crop image when click save button and show crop image to next screen. i try this code but when click save button the show error. how can solve this without any package in flutter?
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  GlobalKey globalKey = GlobalKey();

  Offset framePosition = Offset(100, 100); // Initial position of the frame container
  double frameSize = 150; // Initial size of the frame container
  String backgroundImage = 'images/rose1.png'; // Background image path

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Home Screen"),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          // Background image
          Image.asset(
            backgroundImage,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          ),
          // Frame container
          Positioned(
            left: framePosition.dx,
            top: framePosition.dy,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onPanUpdate: (details) {
                setState(() {
                  framePosition += details.delta;
                });
              },
              child: RepaintBoundary(
                key: globalKey,
                child: Container(
                  width: frameSize,
                  height: frameSize,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 2.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          // Save button
          Positioned(
            bottom: 20,
            right: 20,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => _cropAndNavigate(context),
              child: Text("Save and Next"),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _cropAndNavigate(BuildContext context) async {
    // Capture the image within the frame container
    ui.Image image = await _captureImage(globalKey.currentContext!);

    // Get frame container position and size relative to the background image
    RenderBox containerBox = globalKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    Offset containerPosition = containerBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    double containerWidth = containerBox.size.width;
    double containerHeight = containerBox.size.height;

    // Calculate the crop coordinates relative to the background image
    double left = (framePosition.dx - containerPosition.dx) * 2;
    double top = (framePosition.dy - containerPosition.dy) * 2;
    double width = frameSize * 2;
    double height = frameSize * 2;

    // Crop the image
    Uint8List croppedImage = await _cropImage(image, left.toInt(), top.toInt(), width.toInt(), height.toInt());

    // Navigate to the next screen and pass the cropped image
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => NextScreen(croppedImage: croppedImage),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<ui.Image> _captureImage(BuildContext context) async {
    RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = context.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary;
    ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 2.0);
    return image;
  }

  Future<Uint8List> _cropImage(ui.Image image, int left, int top, int width, int height) async {
    final ByteData? byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    final Uint8List pngBytes = byteData!.buffer.asUint8List();

    // Crop the image
    // Here, you should implement your cropping logic based on the given coordinates
    // For simplicity, I'll just create a copy of the original image
    Uint8List croppedImage = Uint8List.fromList(pngBytes.sublist(left, left + width));

    return croppedImage;
  }
}

class NextScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Uint8List croppedImage;

  NextScreen({required this.croppedImage});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Next Screen"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Image.memory(
          croppedImage,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


i have one assets image and on this image one container i have to crop image when click save button and show crop image to next screen. i try this code but when click save button the show error. how can solve this without any package in flutter?

you definitely cannot use RepaintBoundary for that, imagine you have an image of size 100x100 pixels and want to crop half of that size (for example to 100x50) - your code will scale that image up to full screen size so every pixel will be not 1x1 and this is not what you want, right?

with out RepaintBoundary  what i use for the solve? any example for crop image without any package.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ImageProvider-class.html - here you have the sample code how to get the original ui.Image

show error when click save button -->  Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'cropped.png' ----> the result print line not print and app show the result line await error.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78283566/image-crop-using-the-container-position-in-flutter

To crop an Widget using an offset, you can use CustomClipper and SizedOverflowBox, just need to calculate alignment using some math.
To save an image, the widget need to be under of RepaintBoundary.And you want to display the rest Image, just paint it twice in a stack.
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

final paintKey = GlobalKey();

class Crop extends StatefulWidget {
  const Crop({super.key});

  @override
  State<Crop> createState() => _CropState();
}

class _CropState extends State<Crop> {
  int imageName = 0;
  List<File> files = [];
  double dx = 25;
  double dy = 25;
  double width = 100;
  double height = 100;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final imageWidget = FlutterLogo(size: 200);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Crop'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          ImageView(
              imageWidget: imageWidget,
              dx: dx,
              dy: dy,
              width: width,
              height: height,
              originSize: Size(200, 200)),
          Slider(
              value: dx,
              onChanged: (value) => setState(() => dx = value),
              max: 100),
          Slider(
              value: dy,
              onChanged: (value) => setState(() => dy = value),
              max: 100),
          Slider(
              value: width,
              onChanged: (value) => setState(() => width = value),
              max: 100),
          Slider(
              value: height,
              onChanged: (value) => setState(() => height = value),
              max: 100),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          final boundary = paintKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject()
              as RenderRepaintBoundary;
          final image = await boundary.toImage();
          final byteData =
              await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
          final pngBytes = byteData!.buffer.asUint8List();

          final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
          final file = File('${dir.path}/image$imageName.png');
          await file.writeAsBytes(pngBytes);
          files.add(file);
          imageName += 1;
          if (context.mounted) {
            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  title: const Text('Crop'),
                ),
                body: Center(
                  child: GridView.builder(
                    gridDelegate:
                        const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 4,
                    ),
                    itemCount: files.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Image.file(files[index]);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ));
          }
          // Save the image to the device.
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.save),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ImageView extends StatelessWidget {
  const ImageView({
    super.key,
    required this.imageWidget,
    required this.dx,
    required this.dy,
    required this.width,
    required this.height,
    required this.originSize,
  });

  final FlutterLogo imageWidget;
  final double dx;
  final double dy;
  final double width;
  final double height;
  final Size originSize;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        imageWidget,
        Positioned(
          left: dx,
          top: dy,
          child: Container(
            foregroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.red,
                width: 2,
              ),
            ),
            child: ImageCliper(
                rect: Rect.fromLTWH(dx, dy, width, height),
                size: originSize,
                child: imageWidget),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ImageCliper extends StatelessWidget {
  const ImageCliper({
    super.key,
    required this.child,
    required this.rect,
    required this.size,
  });
  final Widget child;
  final Rect rect;
  final Size size;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    assert(Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
        .contains(rect.bottomRight));
    assert(Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height).contains(rect.topLeft));

    final widthLeft = size.width - rect.width;
    final heightLeft = size.height - rect.height;
    final widthAlignment = rect.left / widthLeft * 2 - 1;
    final heightAlignment = rect.top / heightLeft * 2 - 1;

    return RepaintBoundary(
      key: paintKey,
      child: SizedOverflowBox(
        size: Size(rect.width, rect.height),
        alignment: Alignment(widthAlignment, heightAlignment),
        child: ClipRect(
          clipper: MyCliper(rect),
          child: child,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCliper extends CustomClipper<Rect> {
  MyCliper(this.rect);
  final Rect rect;
  @override
  Rect getClip(Size size) {
    return rect;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant MyCliper oldClipper) {
    return oldClipper.rect != rect;
  }
}

